# How to download List of images into phone gallery ontap using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
List<dynamic> images= ["imageString1","imageString2","imageString3","imageString4","imageString5",];
```

I was able download it individually by getting the index. But i need to download all the images on tap.
I tried image_downloader package and other methods but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Can you show the code how much you have achieved?

Comment: What are the imageString's, the liks, the raw bytes or something other than that

Comment: directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
          String newPath = "";
          print(directory);
          List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
          for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
            String folder = paths[x];
            if (folder != "Android") {
              newPath += "/" + folder;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          newPath = newPath + "/RoofApp";
          directory = Directory(newPath);

Comment: its just String ..

Comment: im unable to copy most f the code here..

Comment: You need to update your question with your code progress... the comment section is just for comments and not for actual code.